# GraphViz, Zest, JUNG2 et cetera for Java

Tags: java, graph, graphviz, zest

Firstly, my goal is to use a library ONLY for laying out nodes in a JavaFx application, so that the size of the node (or box, in my case) is taken in account in laying out.

I tried JUNG2, but wasn't very impressed by it's layout methods.. I would've needed to write one myself to have the results I wanted, which is precisely what I am trying to avoid (because I'm probably not smart enough to write a good one..).

So, now I am looking at GraphViz and Zest.

GraphViz looks like a very impressive and complex beast.

Zest looks interesting too, but how Eclipse-centric is it? Can I use this in a JavaFx application?

Are there others out there? What would you recommend in my case?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have investigated and implemented a Zest-based approach to my problem. Zest runtime is only 800kb, has a nice API and very little dependencies, and, with my own simple collision detection method, works like a wonder. I can post the code if anyone is interested..

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same topic as you are. I recommend GraphViz. Its complex but very powerful and the outcome is very good. I also used Zest, Jung and graphX. The results of all those did not impress me very much. The resulting layout depends on the size of your graph. If you have a complex graph GraphViz would lead to the best results.